# count of one specific item of panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have used following line to get the count of number of

"Read" s  from the specific column (containing  READ,WRITE,NOP)of  a file . which is not csv file but a .out file with \t as delimiter.

```
    data = pd.read_csv('xaa',usecols=[1], header=None,delimiter='\t')
    df2=df1.iloc[start:end,]

    count=df2.str.count("R").sum()
```

I am getting error

> AttributeError:
>
> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

But when i use

```
 if filename.endswith(".csv"): 
        data = pd.read_csv(filename)
df1=data.loc[:,"operation"]
df2=df1.iloc[start:end,] 
count=df2.str.count("R").sum()
```

There is no error. But here i have to enter in each csv file.I have to open the file and insert "operation" in the column I need. KIndly give a soultion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need select column `1` for `Series`, else get one column `DataFrame`:

```
count=df2[1].str.count("R").sum()
```

Or compare by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) and `sum` of `True`s:

```
count=df2[1].eq("R").sum()
```

EDIT:

Another solution is return `Series` in `read_csv` by parameter `squeeze`:

```
s = pd.read_csv('xaa',usecols=[1], header=None,delimiter='\t', squeeze=True)

count=s.iloc[start:end].str.count("R").sum()

#for another solution
#count=s.iloc[start:end].eq("R").sum()
```

**Sample**:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({1:['R','RR','Q']})
print (df2)
    1
0   R
1  RR
2   Q

#count all substrings
count=df2[1].str.count("R").sum()
print (count)
3

#count only strings
count=df2[1].eq("R").sum()
print (count)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `0` to `df2` assignment:

```
data = pd.read_csv('xaa',usecols=[1], header=None,delimiter='\t')
df2=df1.iloc[start:end, 0]

count=df2.str.count("R").sum()
```

And I think it should be:

```
df2 = data.iloc[start:end, 0]
```

But maybe you have some other steps that create `df1`.